# Regular expressions within QGIS expressions: logical operator AND

Tags: qgis, expression, regular-expression, operator

### Context

I use QGIS expressions and want to use regular expressions to identify those strings that contain two words. It's easy to identify those features of the field `text` that contain both `QGIS` **or** `PostGIS` with this expression:

`regexp_match("text", ('QGIS|PostGIS'))>0`

Using with the following four features, no 1. 2 and 3 return `1`, no. 4 returns `0`.

```
1: 'This text contains the words "QGIS" and "PostGIS" as well as others.'

2: 'This text contains the word "QGIS" as well as others.'

3: 'This text contains the word "PostGIS" as well as others.'

4: 'This text contains differents words.'
```

### Question

I now want to identify features that contain both words - thus not `QGIS` **or** `PostGIS`, but `QGIS` **and** `PostGIS` - so only line 1 should return `1`, all others `0`. So if using Regular expressions, the logical operator `OR` is `|`, I'm looking for the equivalent for the operator `AND`.

In this [PCRE Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre), there is an example for `OR`: `a|b -> a or b`, but there is no `and` operator. How to construct an `and` connection?

Comment: There is no _standard_ regex which implements AND, but there is nothing which prevents it from being implemented. In actual practice, it's very hard to come up with real-life scenarios where it would really be practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. There is no `and` operator.
You need to do a lookahead for it to work:

`regexp_match("text", '=?.*QGIS=?.*PostGIS')>0`

I thought it should work regardless of the words' order, but it seems it doesn't. For that, you can add the `or`:

`regexp_match("text", '=?.*(QGIS|PostGIS)=?.*(PostGIS|QGIS)')>0`

**Edit**

Following a comment by @tripleee, there is indeed another way to do this, which simplifies the expression above (*I just edited it for use in QGIS*):

`regexp_match("text", '(QGIS.*PostGIS)|(PostGIS.*QGIS)')>0`

Comment: This is slightly imprecise still. You would probably want to look for `QGIS.*PostGIS|PostGIS.*QGIS` in the lookahead.

Comment: What is `\\\` for? And, @tripleee - how exactly would the whole regex look like that you propose?

Comment: Actually that could be the entire expression if you just want to check whether both are present. So `regexp_match("text", ('QGIS.*PostGIS|PostGIS.*QGIS ')>0` which can be read out as `QGIS` followed by anything followed by `PostGIS`, or `PostGIS` followed by anything followed by `QGIS`. I don't know enouga about the system to tell whether this is sufficient (I came here from another site because this question came up in Hot Network Questions and picked my curiosity).

Comment: @Babel The `\\` are not really needed in this example, because they are used as escape characters. I edited the answer to also include the solution proposed by @tripleee with minor adjustments for it to work in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id60

```
"text" ~ 'PostGIS' AND "text" ~ 'QGIS'
```

[image]